# How to get the number of unread threads in INBOX with Gmail API?

Tags: gmail-api

I tried to use the list thread method:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{MyEmailAddress}/threads?labelIds=INBOX&labelIds=UNREAD&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

The resultSizeEstimate does not match the number next to my inbox in Gmail web app.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Gmail API now provides total and unread counts for messages and threads on each Label using the Labels.Get() method.  See:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/release-notes
and
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels

Answer (score 5):

Turn conversation view off in the Gmail UI in order to get an accurate count of the message (not threads) in your inbox.

You can also use:

in:inbox is:unread

as the query in both the UI and API. Remove the labelId parameters.

Comment: I was trying to get the accurate count of threads, and not messages. But I will try the query instead of label.

Answer (score 0):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{email}/messages?labelIds=UNREAD&labelIds=INBOX&fields=messages%2FthreadId
```

"messages/threadId" will count the number of unread threads but will list the same thread multiple times if the thread has multiple messages. Store them in an array and check the array as you fill it for matching "threadId" identifiers and ignore duplicates.