# Incomplete response from Gmail API threads.list

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

I plot the number of emails in my inbox over time using the Gmail API and I'm seeing a lot of drop-outs, where for whatever reason I'm getting an incomplete count of messages back at single time points.

My plots are here: https://plot.ly/~tdsmith/2 -- the "drop-outs" I'm complaining about are where the trace shoots downwards and then recovers to the previous level at the next timepoint.

The code I'm using to count emails is here: https://github.com/tdsmith/gmail-plotly/blob/master/gmail-plotly.py#L47-L64

What can I do to diagnose these faults?

Comment: don't speak python. but you should try equivalent REST APIs with any rest client(postman, advanced REST client), that should help. try list all messages instead of threads, etc.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468457/how-to-get-the-number-of-unread-threads-in-inbox-with-gmail-api

Comment: Thanks for the link; that is actually what I'm doing, since I discovered the estimates were unreliable.

Comment: Could you try the threads.list with a single query, this would make it easier to troubleshoot. It would be interesting to see if the changes are occurring in some type of pattern.